# Age verification. Varien.DateElement vs Varien.DOB

Tags: javascript, magento-1.6, validation

I try to add a age verification to the day of birth field on the registration page.
For now I added this code to the `Varien.DateElement` validate function in the `js\varien\js.js` file:

```
today = new Date();
var dateLegal = new Date(today.getFullYear() - 18, today.getMonth(), today.getDate() );
console.log(dateLegal);
if (test.valueOf() > dateLegal.valueOf()) {
    error = 'You must be 18.......';
}
```

This works how I want it. The problem I have with this is, `Varien.DateElement` is for every date fields. There is a `Varien.DOB` special for day of birth. I tried to add there a validate function, but it will be never called.

```
Varien.DOB = Class.create();
Varien.DOB.prototype = {
    initialize: function(selector, required, format) {
        var el = $$(selector)[0];
        var container       = {};
        container.day       = Element.select(el, '.dob-day input')[0];
        container.month     = Element.select(el, '.dob-month input')[0];
        container.year      = Element.select(el, '.dob-year input')[0];
        container.full      = Element.select(el, '.dob-full input')[0];
        container.advice    = Element.select(el, '.validation-advice')[0];

        new Varien.DateElement('container', container, required, format);
    },
    validate: function() {
        var error = false;
       console.log("validate called"); //I will never be called
    }
};
```

So is there a better way to add a validation then to place it in `Varien.DateElement` ?

Answer (score 2):

Please check out [this excellent post](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/post/6579512188/magento-custom-form-validation) on creating a custom validation. Adding a second type of validation is cleaner as it doesn't require you to edit existing code.

In your case it would be something like

```
Validation.add('validate-dob-18','You are not 18',function(value){
   [...]
   calculate nr of years
   [...]
   if(years > 18)
   {
      return true;
   }
   return false;
});
```

I would suggest also adding PHP validation as Javascript validation as anything but secure.

Also, to work more easily with dates and times check out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thx for the link. As BOD are 3 fields together I'm not yet sure how to use this on this "combo" fields.

Comment: as far as I know the DOB field values are set in a hidden input `dob-full` and that's actually what's validated. with the class given to the 3 inputs. Otherwise, a less nicer option, would be to retrieve the 3 values from the validation function hardcoded

Comment: I try the method in the link again. But still have no luck get it working. What I have done: in the dob.phtml there is a div with id "dob-full". I added `class="validate-dob"` to the inputfield in this div. Then I added this JS: `Validation.add('validate-dob','test',function(the_field_value){ if(the_field_value == 'test'){ return true;} return false;});` But this dont work at all. Any idea?

Comment: Isn't `validate-dob` an already existing check? I would use a unique name that doesn't exist yet

Comment: no it's not. And the name isn't the problem anyway. I tried also `validate-alpha` (only letters) and it passed the validation too. I think a problem is, that the dob-full is not filled until DateElement gets validated. I could validate the single items (year, month, day) but then I get the error message at the wrong place. Any ideas left?

Comment: Ill take a look over the weekend. We should be able to come up with a solution right? :)

Comment: I did a work around now - bit ugly - but at least it works and I don't have to overwrite core files. (see my answer)

Comment: Nice! well I'm still gonna have a look at it cause it annoys me we couldn't find a 'nice' solution. Ill let you know

Comment: yes a nice soulution would be nice :)

Comment: did you find any nice solution?

Comment: not yet, but in the mean time I have to build it myself to for a client so ill let you know what I find ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I have so far is a own validate rule `validate-dob`. Then I add `validate-dob` as a class to the day/month/year inputfields. As errortext I give a single space ' ' and fill the real errormessage in the field: jQuery(".customer-dob > .validation-advice") (that's the errorfield for the hidden dob-full field).

```
Validation.add('validate-dob',' ',function(field_value){
    console.log("validate-dob");
        var today = new Date();
        var dateLegal = new Date(today.getFullYear() - 18, today.getMonth(), today.getDate() );
        var test = new Date(jQuery(".dob-year input").val(), jQuery(".dob-month input").val()-1, jQuery(".dob-day input").val());
        console.log(test);
        if (test.valueOf() > dateLegal.valueOf() && test.getFullYear() <= today.getFullYear()) { //falls test grösser also Heute - 18j. UND Testjahr nicht grösser als aktuelles Jahr (weil diese überprüfung findet in js.js statt)
            var dob_error = '<?php echo $this->__('Die Zustellung von Wein und Spirituosen kann gemäss geltendem Recht nur an Personen über 18 Jahren erfolgen.'); ?>';
            jQuery(".customer-dob > .validation-advice").html(dob_error);
            jQuery(".customer-dob > .validation-advice").show();
            console.log("return false");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

I'm not that happy with it, cause it says the single fields (day, month, year) are wrong, even if they are not. At least it works and I dont have to overwrite core files.

Answer (score 1):

add this javascript class:

```
Varien.DOB18 = Class.create();
Varien.DOB18.prototype = {
    initialize: function(selector, required, format) {
        var el = $$(selector)[0];
        var container       = {};
        container.day       = Element.select(el, '.dob-day input')[0];
        container.month     = Element.select(el, '.dob-month input')[0];
        container.year      = Element.select(el, '.dob-year input')[0];
        container.full      = Element.select(el, '.dob-full input')[0];
        container.advice    = Element.select(el, '.validation-advice')[0];

        var minDate = new Date('1/1/1900');
        var maxDate = new Date();
        maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getYear() - 18);
        new Varien.dateRangeDate('container', container, required, format).setDateRange(minDate, maxDate);
    }
};
```

minDate is necessary to overcome Varien bug...

Comment: Thanks for the share. I tried your snippet and it works well, except, you need to call   `maxDate.getFullYear()` method instead of `maxDate.getYear()`

Comment: so many extensions provider selling for [age verification](https://www.mageants.com/age-verification-extension-for-magento-2.html) you can try and test demo